# omit NAs when tallying using dplyr summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

My question involves summarising a dataframe with multiple columns(50 columns) using the `summarise_each` function in dplyr. 
The data entries in the columns are binary(0=negative, 1=positive) and I aim to get the colsums and percentage positives.
The issue is that some columns have NAs and I wish to exclude these in the calculations of totals and percentages. 
Below is a minimal example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df=data.frame(
  x1=c(1,0,0,NA,0,1,1,NA,0,1),
  x2=c(1,1,NA,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x3=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x4=c(1,0,NA,1,0,0,NA,0,0,1),
  x5=c(1,1,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,0,1))

> df
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1   1  1  0  1  1
2   0  1  1  0  1
3   0 NA  0 NA NA
4  NA  1  1  1  1
5   0  1  1  0  1
6   1  0  0  0  1
7   1 NA NA NA NA
8  NA NA NA  0  1
9   0  0  0  0  0
10  1  1  1  1  1

df %>%
  summarise_each(funs(total.count=n(), positive.count=sum(.,na.rm=T),positive.pctg=sum(.,na.rm=T)*100/n())) %>%
  gather(key,fxn,x1_total.count:x5_positive.pctg) %>%
  separate(key,c("col","funcn"),sep="\\_") %>%
  spread(funcn,fxn)

  col positive.count positive.pctg total.count
1  x1              4            40          10
2  x2              5            50          10
3  x3              4            40          10
4  x4              3            30          10
5  x5              7            70          10
```

What I was hoping to get in the table above is for example, the total(total.count) for x1 as:

```
length(df$x1[!is.na(df$x1)])

[1] 8
```

Instead I get an equivalent of the following, which includes the NAs:

```
length(df$x1)

[1] 10
```

and I also want the percentage(positive.pctg) for x1 as:

```
sum(df$x1,na.rm=T)/length(df$x1[!is.na(df$x1)])

[1] 0.5
```

Instead I get an equivalent of the following, which includes the NAs:

```
sum(df$x1,na.rm=T)/length(df$x1)

[1] 0.4
```

How can I do the the count in dplyr ommiting NAs? it seems the functions `n()` or `length()` do not take any
arguments like `na.omit/na.rm/complete.cases`.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
df %>%
    summarise_each(funs(total.count=sum(!is.na(.)), positive.count=sum(.,na.rm=T),positive.pctg=sum(.,na.rm=T)*100/sum(!is.na(.))))%>%
    gather(key,fxn,x1_total.count:x5_positive.pctg) %>%
    separate(key,c("col","funcn"),sep="\\_") %>%
    spread(funcn,fxn)
```